# Sporadic Selenium Chrome WebDriver timeouts starting with chrome 85

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I have a few .NET Core automation projects using Selenium and running against Chrome. The builds are running in a Jenkins pipeline, currently running the tests on a Linux build agent.

These tests all ran perfectly when we were running against chrome 83, but when we had our dev ops team upgrade to chrome 85 we started seeing sporadic timeouts. When the timeouts occur we see the following error for each test:

```
Error Message:
OneTimeSetUp: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:41307/session/008798b4a2c52b867ec157b20d89f9b9/url timed out after 60 seconds.
    ----> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The operation was canceled.
    ----> System.IO.IOException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation canceled.
    ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Operation canceled
```

This timeout is not isolated to a single test, but if it happens, the same error message will appear for every test in the test run.

This happens, on average, every 2-3 times the tests run. It is not a question of timing as sometimes scheduled runs succeed and other times fail, and I can run the tests over and over, back to back, and will get successes and failures randomly intermixed.

What I have tried so far:

- Running on a Windows agent instead of a Linux agent (fails more often with the timeout, almost 100% of the time)
- Increasing the timeout (all the way up to 10 minutes and we still see the exact same behavior)
- Upgraded chrome/chromedriver to 86 and still see the same behavior
- Tried using Selenium 4.0 beta package

It is also worth noting that we have not seen this happen a single time running locally through Visual Studio. It is only when executing these tests through our Jenkins pipeline that we see this behavior.

Any ideas on how to resolve these random timeout failures?

edit:

Adding the code I am using to initialize the chromedriver:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--no-sandbox", "--start-maximized");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080", "--headless"); // Comment out if running locally to see execution
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("safebrowsing.enabled", "true");
WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

The server we are running against is headless but I left the start-maximized flag in place for easier local debugging.

edit 2:

This is the rest of the code executed within the OneTimeSetUp method which utilizes the webDriver:

```
public LoginService(IWebDriver webDriver)
{
    _webDriver = webDriver;
}

public void OpenAndLoginToApplication(string applicationUrl, string username, string password)
{
    _webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(string.Format(LoginPageUrlTemplate, applicationUrl));

    _webDriver.SetInputFieldValue(By.Id(UsernameFieldId), InputFieldType.Text, username);
    _webDriver.SetInputFieldValue(By.Id(PasswordFieldId), InputFieldType.Text, password);

    _webDriver.ClickAndConfirmByElementVisibility(By.Id(LoginButtonId), By.Id(LoggedInUserDropdownId));
}
```

Comment: At what point in the life cycle of the web driver object do these timeouts occur? Is it during the initialization of the web driver? When calling methods in the web driver or elements?

Comment: @GregBurghardt This occurs after chromedriver has started up. I get the message, "ChromeDriver was started successfully." and then the logs will list the above error message under each test name as the failure reason for the test. Unfortunately though I do not have access to these systems, so the only logs I can get are the output of the Jenkins build itself, so I have not been able to trace it any more granularly than that up to this point.

Comment: Each Jenkins build should show a full stack trace, that includes method calls in your test. Plus, you should be able to generate a test results file when calling `dotnet test` or whichever command line utility is used to run the tests. Unfortunately unless we know the full stack trace, I'm not sure we can help you.

Comment: So is it safe to say these random timeouts occur at any point in the lifecycle of the web driver object, not just initialization?

Comment: The error posted above that shows in Jenkins is the full stack trace listed in the test results file. This has been my problem in trying to do any further troubleshooting is that I don't have more to a stack trace than this to work from. 

In terms of where they occur, I can say that what I see is the message that chromedriver started successfully, then after enough time for the timeout passes, all test cases are simultaneously written to the log with the same failure message.

Comment: A relevant note I just thought of with this too is that I am using a SetUpFixture with OneTimeSetup at the top level of the project, and that is where all driver initialization is occurring. So the error happening in that scope is why all fail simultaneously with the same message.

Comment: Can you add the driver initialization code? Any and all that would be relevant?

Comment: I added the driver initialization code above. I also tried adding extensive logging to output to the Jenkins console each step of the OneTimeSetUp method, but I haven't been able to get it to actually spit out to the console.

Comment: So the exception is occurring in the code you posted?

Comment: I don't think it is, no, since the chromedriver is actually starting, but no attempting at logging out to the console to get better information has been successful, and the output doesn't give me a line number or anything else. The other work with the web driver is simply opening the application and logging in, which I will past the code for above as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to figure out why this was happening, but I was able to solve this problem.

I found that the timeout was happening on Navigate() to the application. No matter how much I increased the timeout, I would still get the failure. However, a subsequent Navigate() call would succeed.

So my solution to this was to simply retry navigating to the application url if we receive a WebDriverException (the timeout exception) on the initial call.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the web driver, maybe?  I'm wondering if that could be fixed in a less "hacky" way.  Or if this workaround is necessary.

Comment: It strikes me the same way, but unfortunately I am not able to reproduce this behavior at all on any system I have more access to to track down logs and such, and even where it does occur, it's generally sporadic. So I wouldn't be able to open any kind of actionable bug report.